# Word for saying something and meaning the other

Tags: single-word-requests

I cant recall the word for saying something and meaning the other. For example, if someone says I do not want to fight but really intends to fight, what do you call that?

Thanks.

Comment: You're looking for something other than _lying_?

Comment: Lying is more of a generic term and I am looking for a word that clearly describes my definition. Perhaps I should have rephrased my topic question / definition to: Word for saying something but meaning the opposite.

Comment: Is the person hearing this "something" intended to deduce the real meaning?

Comment: That would be ***sarcasm***

Comment: It can deduce, but sarcasm is not the word im looking for. I heard this word from Suits series. It can mean, Suggesting the opposite of what you intend and proving its flaw in order to convince the recipient of your real intention.

Comment: "Disingenuous"?

Comment: @WS2 I was just about to type that! Possibly also *baiting* someone. Sometimes it's also the opposite - Saying they want to fight, but actually not wanting to (which would be a bluff)

Comment: "Suggesting the opposite of what you intend and proving its flaw in order to convince the recipient of your real intention." This is actually a different concept than what you are asking in your question. Please edit and make it clear what you mean. That's why people voted to put your question on hold.

Comment: Is the opposite word used *deliberately* or is it unintentional? If it's used deliberately, what's the intent behind its use?

Comment: @JasonBassford There is a form of irony, often used in Britain, where the opposite is used to achieve both humour and emphasis e.g. "You were threatening to come and visit us last week, but you didn't show up."

Comment: This is kind of late, but wouldn't the word be one of bluffing, sarcasm, or verbal irony?

Answer (score 1):

Bluffing.

Definition: try to deceive someone as to one's abilities or intentions

Comment: Hello Jupitero, please could you add a link to that definition?

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of [Negative Reverse Selling](https://www.salefish.sandler.com/blog/sales_negativereverse_selling)?

Typically, one gives a negative response to a question in order to get more information before answering.

Or suppose the client is hesitating in making a decision:

> … you can soften them up first and then hit them with a negative
>   reverse haymaker:
>
> - “*I completely understand. I don’t think you’re ready to make this
>     investment.*”
> - “*That’s a valid concern. I guess we’re done here.*”
>
> There’s definitely some risk involved in this response. But in the
>   right situation the prospect will defend their readiness and sell
>   themselves on your product.
>
> — [Negative Reverse Selling: You're Not Ready to Read This Article](https://www.activecampaign.com/blog/negative-reverse-selling)

In the original question example, perhaps you might say something like "*You don't really want to fight, do you?*", forcing the other person to make the decision to fight.

---

Or perhaps you're thinking of a [Freudian slip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freudian_slip)?

That's where you accidentally say one thing but you really mean your mother.

Answer (score 0):

[**Equivocating**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equivocal) -- The use of equivocal language:

> 1a : subject to two or more interpretations and usually used to mislead or confuse

See also being [**disingenuous**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disingenuous)

And, [**prevaricating**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prevaricating).

These are all really fancy words for lying. But, they carry a sense of presenting the falsehood in language that helps to obscure the truth.

---

Based upon your comment below your question proving your opponent's point to show it's flaw by taking it to it's illogical conclusion:

> Suggesting the opposite of what you intend and proving its flaw in order to convince the recipient of your real intention.

[**Reductio ad absurdum**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum)

Your opponent says the Earth is flat. You say, "Of course it is. That's why people keep falling off the edge all the time!"

Your "proof" is actually a disproof of their argument.